# Check div's margin than move it every one second

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The `div` should move 9 times and than it should stop. Problem is that it moves only one time. Anyone has Idea for solving this? Thanks

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var id=1;
  setInterval(move,1000);
  function move(){
   if($(".block").css("margin-left") < "100px"){
    $(".block").animate({marginLeft: "+=10px"});

   }

  }
 });
```

```css
.block{
 padding: 15px;
    background-color: orange;
    float: left;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #b1b1b1;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block"></block>
```

Comment: 1. You are not looping it 9 times, only executing it once. 2. even if you'd loop, your if statement is limited to 100px, so nothing would happen.

Comment: I am looping it, `setInterval(move,1000);`

Answer (score 1):

`"Npx" < "100px"` will not work. **Those are Strings!**

You should use `parseInt()` to convert some `margin-left` string to Number and that you can compare using `< 100`.
Also, you don't need a `setInterval()`, use the `.animate()` callback to recall your `move` function

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      
  (function move(){
    if( parseInt($(".block").css("margin-left"), 10) < 100) {
      $(".block").delay(1000).animate({marginLeft: "+=10px"}, move);
    }
  }());
  
});
```

```css
.block{
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: orange;
  float: left;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #b1b1b1;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block"></block>
```

P.S: it'll move 10 times :)